# How to create Volume in Kubernetes like Volume in Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I am new to Kubernetes and trying to create Volume in it like we create in Docker Compose.

Docker Compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  my-service:
    container_name: my-container
    image: my-image:0.0.1
    volumes:
      - ./src/main/resources:/src/main/resources
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
```

I'm creating `/src/main/resources volume` in Docker Container. Now I want to create volume like this in `k8's`. What I've tried is:

My Deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deployment

spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-label
  template:
    metadata:
      name: my-pod
      labels:
        app: my-label
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-container
          image: my-image:0.0.1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8082
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /src/main/resources
              name: my-volume
      volumes:
        - name: my-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /home/my-user/src/main/resources
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service

spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: my-label
  ports:
    - port: 8082
      targetPort: 8082
      nodePort: 31802
```

Above is successfully creating the volume but it is not pasting the contents of `/home/my-user/src/main/resources` in volume `/src/main/resources`. I've checked it using command `kubectl exec -it pod-name -- /bin/sh`.

Here is my build.sbt how I am creating docker-image using sbt-native-packager:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.*

ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "my-project"
  )

enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)

Docker / packageName := "my-image"

Docker / version := "0.0.1"
dockerExposedPorts := Seq(8082)

dockerChmodType := DockerChmodType.UserGroupWriteExecute
dockerPermissionStrategy := DockerPermissionStrategy.CopyChown
dockerAdditionalPermissions += (DockerChmodType.UserGroupPlusExecute, "/var/run/")

Docker / daemonUserUid := None
Docker / daemonUser := "root"
```

Guide me how can I do this?

Comment: Is the rest of your application in your image?  Why do you need to bind-mount this specific directory?  Can you delete the Compose `volumes:`, and the corresponding Kubernetes setup?

Comment: (Since Kubernetes is a multi-host clustered remote container environment, it _can't_ bind-mount local files into a container.)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy contents which are required in docker container using `build.sbt`.

just add following lines in your build.sbt:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.MappingsHelper.directory

Universal / mappings ++= directory("src/main/resources")
```

By adding above lines in your build.sbt then when you will hit `docker:publishLocal` it will copy the content from **src/main/resources** to docker image (**/opt/docker/src/main/resources**).

This will work for your case without creating volume in k8's.